# Boosting Filtered query based on field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following filtered query and want to use the custom_score query or the custom_filters_score query to boost the results based on a specific field value. However, I'm hitting errors such as:

```
No query registered for [custom_filters_score]]; 
No query registered for [custom_score]];
```

Where am I going wrong? Any help greatly appreciated !

Here is the query:

```
{
"query": {
    "custom_score": {
        "query": {
            "filtered": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "constant_score": {
                                    "query": {
                                        "match": {
                                            "question": {
                                                "query": "diabetes"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "dis_max": {
                                    "queries": [
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "question": {
                                                            "query": "diabetes"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 0.01
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "answer_text": {
                                                            "query": "diabetes"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 0.0001
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "dis_max": {
                                    "queries": [
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "match_phrase": {
                                                        "question_phrase": {
                                                            "query": "what is diabetes",
                                                            "slop": 0
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 100
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "match_phrase": {
                                                        "question_phrase": {
                                                            "query": "what is diabetes",
                                                            "slop": 1
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 50
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "match_phrase": {
                                                        "question_phrase": {
                                                            "query": "what is diabetes",
                                                            "slop": 2
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 33
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "match_phrase": {
                                                        "question_phrase": {
                                                            "query": "what is diabetes",
                                                            "slop": 3
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 25
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "question_group_four",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 0.1
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "question_group_five",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 0.15
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_no_synonyms_20",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 35
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_no_synonyms_15",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 25
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_no_synonyms_10",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 15
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_20",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 28
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_15",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 16
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_10",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 13
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_05",
                                                        "query": "what__is__diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 4
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "dis_max": {
                                    "queries": [
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "question_group_four",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 0.1
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "question_group_five",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 0.15
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_no_synonyms_20",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 35
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_no_synonyms_15",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 25
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_no_synonyms_10",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 15
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_20",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 28
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_15",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 16
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_10",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 13
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "constant_score": {
                                                "query": {
                                                    "query_string": {
                                                        "default_field": "concept_words_05",
                                                        "query": "diabetes"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "boost": 4
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "disable_coord": true
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "and": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "posted_by_expert": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "tip_question": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "show_in_work_queue": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "verified_answers_count": {
                                    "gt": 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "script": "_score * doc['my_numeric_field'].value"
    }
},
"sort": [
    "_score",
    {
        "count_words_with_high_concepts": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    },
    {
        "popularity": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    },
    {
        "length": {
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
],
"fields": [],
"size": 10,
"from": 0}
```

Answer (score 5):

These two queries are not available in latest versions of elastic search after 0.90.4 . So if you are using elastic search > 0.90.4( which is a pretty old version), you will have to use  [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)  which replaced  [Custom Filters Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-filters-score-query.html#query-dsl-custom-filters-score-query)  after 0.90.4 version

Comment: The solution did work. However, the performance of the queries have suffered greatly. They're taking 1.3 to 3.6 sec Originally I thought of using rescore because it would not affect performance. Is there a way around this using function score or any other method? Thanks.